# Advice for handling default GEM_PATH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When I upgraded from rubygems 1.3.5 to 1.3.7, my GEM_PATH changed.  `gem environment` gives me

```
- GEM PATHS:
- /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
- /home/me/.gem/ruby/1.8
```

... whereas it was previously `/var/lib/gems/1.8`

How would you handle this?

1. I could set GEM_PATH, but this seems a bit messy, as I'd have to do this for my shell, and each of my application's `environment.rb` files.
2. I could try to set the default, but I imagine this would involve making changes to default installation files, which seems like a bad idea.
3. Should I just delete the old dir and reinstall all gems?  This sounds safe, but time-consuming.

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid the problem by using [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/).
You can create and [use new gemsets](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/gemsets/using/), separate from your [current](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rubies/default/) gems.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I don't want to maintain multiple gemsets, and it turns out simply copying the old gem dir to the new location works... so far.

Answer (score 1):

The gem path changing doesn't really have anything do with updating RubyGems. It has to do with the fact that you have *two* parallel installations of RubyGems: the one from the Debian package repository which you installed via APT and another one.

The solution is simple: Don't Do That.

The Debian RubyGems has been patched to install its gems in `/var/lib/gems`, the RubyGems from RubyGems.Org uses `/usr/lib/ruby/gems` if that is writeable, `~/.gem` otherwise.

You should *never* mix several different installations of RubyGems, and you should *particularly* not mix Debian-RubyGems and plain RubyGems. *Either* install RubyGems from Debian and use *only* that, and *only* update it with APT *or* install RubyGems from RubyGems.Org and use *only* that and *only* update it via `gem update --system`. Note that this transitively also applies to YARV, which contains its own copy of RubyGems. *If* you use Debian-RubyGems, then you must *also* use the Debian-packaged versions of YARV, because only the Debian packages of YARV have been patched to remove RubyGems and use the Debian-provided one.

Somehow, you managed to "update" your Debian-RubyGems to a plain one, which isn't really an update but actually more like a separate installation. This shouldn't actually happen, because the Debian-RubyGems has the update functionality removed. This is what *my* Debian-installed RubyGems prints:

```
gem update --system
# ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
# gem update --system is disabled on Debian. RubyGems can be updated using the 
# official Debian repositories by aptitude or apt-get.
```

1.3.5 is pretty old, so maybe that error check wasn't in there, although I doubt it. AFAIK that error check was introduced somewhere in the 1.2 timeframe.

Comment: Thanks, I realize now I should not use the Debian repository if I want to control my own fate.  Fortunately, I can just move my gems by copying the directory and use the rubygems.org way going forward.